# Spring JBoss compatibility

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, wildfly, jboss7.x

Can anyone please share me the compatibility matrix for Spring and JBOss.
Currently I am using Spring 5.3.14. Need to know the JBOSS EAP and JBOSS AS version for the same.

Also previously in context class in web.xml I used context class as `com.javaetmoi.spring.JBossZmlWebApplicationContext`
After upgrading to 5.3 I removed it.
But It is erroring out:

```
Could not open ServletContext resources [/<none>] org.springfrmework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from servletcontextreaource. Nested exception is Java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: It can't find a file - it doesn't look like a compatibility issue.

Comment: Previously it was using com.vfs2.javaeatmoi jar to match the files. I removed it as it was for spring 4 what to use for spring 5